# How can I code a cooldown to a key press?

Tags: javascript

In my game, there is a "boost" option that pushs the player forward when they press Left Shift.
The problem is you can spam the button and go flying across the map.
To resolve this issue I want to add a small cooldown that will give the player good speed, but also won't let the player exploit the feature by speeding across the entire map in 5 seconds.

I have tried looking up how to fix the issue but nothing helped because the code was in something like c++ or python.

Here is the code for my movement:

```
function Input() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    var name = event.key;
    var code = event.code;
    if (code == "ArrowRight" || code == "KeyD") {
        velX+= 5
    }
    if (code == "ArrowDown" || code == "KeyS") {
        velY+= 5
    }
    if (code == "ArrowUp" || code == "KeyW") {
        velY-= 5
    }
    if (code == "ArrowLeft" || code == "KeyA") {
        velX-= 5
        
    }
    if (code == "ShiftLeft") {
        velX *= 2
        velY *= 2
    }
    

    }, false);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: why not just set a ceiling to the speed?

Comment: Also look for debouncing, you can use that to kill any click more than X

Comment: Is worth mentioning that keydown is one the events where if you hold it down, it'll spam the same event, so you don't have to spam the button to spam, and this applies to all the switch cases. You probably mean to have `if (event.repeat) return` to prevent this.

Comment: @trincot because it's a small boost, not a sprint. lol

Comment: So what do you want then? That a boost cannot be repeated until its effect is *completely* over, or *half* over,  or over for 1 minute, or ...what exactly? Do you really want a cooldown of the keypress event (so the player cannot change direction anymore)?

Comment: Yes, I'm very sorry if I phrased my post wrong, but think of it as the dash ability from Celeste.

Answer (score 0):

just add a variable named Pressed (or something dosent matter) set it to false and when the user uses that boost set it to true
and let a setTimeout with the cooldown u want that boost to be run in bg
when the time reaches 0 set Preseed to false
also make sure to check if the Pressed is false before running the boost code